# Mysql Select one record from another

Tags: mysql, join

Hello I have huge problem. In mysql I have 3 tables. `Clients` , `Groups` and `GroupCross` . So I have :

```
SELECT * FROM clients AS cl 
INNER JOIN groupscross AS cr ON cl.cid=cr.cid;
```

(So now I have matched id in clients with id in groupcross . In groupcross I have also table :cgid .

Now I have data from cr.cgid like : `50,50,60,55,60` so when I command :)
`WHERE cr.cgid='function to get  id'` .

I get all cgid:(50,50,60,55,60)

And here is **my question:**

How can I do to have all id without 60 ?
I add when I write: `WHERE cr.cgid <>60` it shows me all record from database when I want only 50,50,55

Comment: could you print exactly the full request you have, show the response and explain what you want as a result because it's not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IN` statement -

```
SELECT * 
FROM `clients` AS `cl` 
INNER JOIN `groupscross` AS `cr` 
ON `cl`.`cid` = `cr`.`cid`
WHERE `cr`.`cgid` IN(50,55)
```

Comment: It shows me only records from all database which have id 60 . I want to show records feom clients where id of group is different than 60

Comment: The query that I just wrote will not show records with id 60, only 50 or 55.

Comment: Yea but from whole database . I want to show record only from id which i get from function : cr.cgid='myfunction' . After this function call i get cgid record 50,55,50,60,60 and i want to separate 50 and 55 . When i call Yor method i get 50,55 from all database

Comment: I'm sorry, you're request is not very clear. Can you edit your original question to show the output you desire?